# rerender React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, javascript-objects, react-state

So i m trying to rerender a list by filtered values. The list is already rendered with all the values. I want to render it again with a dropdown of options. I get my values from a JSON locally.

[
{
"brand": "toyota",
"model": "corona",
"cylinders": 4,
"horsepower": 96,
"origin": "Japan",
"price": 40000
},
...
]

```
export const FilterBrand = (props) => {
  const brands = props.list
    .map((vehicle) => vehicle.brand)
    .filter((value, index, vehicle) => vehicle.indexOf(value) === index);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    // console.log(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <select onChange={(e) => props.handleChange(e.target.value)}>
      {brands.map((vehicle, key) => (
        <option key={key} value={key}>
          {vehicle}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}; here is my component



<div className="filter-brand">
 <FilterBrand
 list={list}
 handleChange={(value) => console.log(value)}
 />
</div here is my component imported in main app, JSON is also imported in main app and passed as props in my component.
How can I render it again based on the options from the dropdown?
```

Comment: From Where are you getting the `list` ?

Comment: it s imported in my main app index.js import importedList from "./components/assets/vehicleList.json"; and saved as a variable const list = importedList;

Comment: How do you filter the brands?

Comment: ```export const FilterBrand = (props) => {
const brands = props.list
.map((vehicle) => vehicle.brand)
.filter((value, index, vehicle) => vehicle.indexOf(value) === index);```

Answer (score 2):

use a [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to store the 'results' to show then use a function or two to change 'results' based on the 'filter' selected. When a change in state occurs react will automatically re-render the view for you